# conjure-up canonical-kubernetes

Tags: maas, conjure-up

Ubuntu 17.04

I have MAAS and 2 nodes,

I need to deploy local kubernetes on my MAAS,

One nodes goes to juju bootstrap and just one node left, How can I install kubernetes through conjure-up on just one node(machine) it seems it looks for 9 machine by default, when you look at juju status after running "conjure-up canonical-kubernetes"

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to press the **Architect** button in the Application list view to pin those applications to the 2 machines.